# How to view package applicability rules through SCCM

Tags: sccm

I have created my own custom packages with different applicability rules for Installable and Installed conditions and published the packages to the SCCM server.

Is there are any way to view these rules through the SCCM client? I'm using SCCM 2007 and see no way of finding these. It's clear that SCCM must have parsed these in order to identify the Required/Not required/Installed numbers.

I believe I can get this info by looking at the created cab file but seems strange if its not available through the client.